# c programme for loop: execution sequence

Tags: c, for-loop

The following code is simple, What I want to know is the execution time for **++counter**. I know for a **for** loop, **count<5** is the first condition to check,but then for the execution time of **++counter** I'm not so sure. line 1, 2 or 3, which is the place to execute increment?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int counter;
/* counter for loop */

for (counter = 0; counter < 5; ++counter) {  // 1
printf("x %d\n", counter+1);  // 2
} //3
return (0);
}
```

And the result is

```
x 1    
x 2    
x 3    
x 4    
x 5
```

Comment: The result you shown is not compatible with the program you posted.

Comment: And the results you got together with the info available on that increment operator could easilly indicate you what happens when. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not getting the `X 0` for `++counter` [Ideone Output](http://ideone.com/8mlrbJ)

and the position of ++counter wont matter for your change in X value as instrumentation for the for loop is done is after the execution of one cycle(assuming the expression is true)

Check this link fo rtutorial on for loop [Loops](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html)

Comment: My fault. I tried different version and got several results and mixed them up. It is always 1 for the first element. and Thank you for your Loop tutorial. that's clear!

Answer (score 0):

++counter is executed after printf("x %d\n", counter+1); in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

To boil it down, a for loop can be transformed into a while loop like such:

```
for (initialization,condition,iteration)
{
    //code
}

initialization
while(condition)
{ 
    //code
    iteration
}
```

so i++ or ++i are executed after the loop runs through, and then the condition is checked for the loop to be run again.

Answer (score 0):

You can interpret the following for-loop

```
for (variable initialization; ending condition; variable update) {
    // code
}
```

as a shortened while loop

```
variable initialization
while(ending condition) {
    // code
    variable update
}
```

thus your `counter++` or `++counter` is executed after the statements in the loop.

To be fair, it doesn't matter which increment, either post- or prefix you want to use. But performance wise, prefix is a bit faster then postfix in **some circumstances**. IF you are interested in why, you can refer to [this explanation](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/increment-pre-post-speed.html).